# excel 2016 how to make reference by concatenating content of several cells

Tags: excel, vba

I nave few pages in a workbook. I want to create a formula that refers to a cell (C6) in another page (Capacity_D63) by concatenating the contents of several cells (C17 that contains text Capacity_, cell B7 that contains text D63, and  C6 on the page Capacity_D63), that is, I want to get the formula =Capacity_D63!C$6. 
My formula is

```
="="&$C$17&B7&"!$C$6"
```

As the result, the formula in a cell look OK but it is not a formula but just a text.

Where am I wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to populate a cell with the correct formula through vba or are you typing the above as a formula in the sheet?

Comment: In the sheet. Thank you. I got the comprehensive answer from Jeeped.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=address(6, 3, 4, 1, $c$17&b7)
' or as a formula
=indirect(address(6, 3, 4, 1, c17&b7))
' to make yours into a true cell rference,
=indirect($C$17&B7&"!C6")
```

You don't require $ absolute markers when using text that only looks like a cell reference. It will not change when dragged or copied to a new destination.

You were constructing a text string that looked like a worksheet cell reference but it was just a text string. The INDIRECT wrapper converts those text strings to usable worksheet cell references.